# This program stores text message inside a class how can i print this in the class

Tags: python, class

```
import datetime
class SMS_Inbox:
    def ___init___(self):
        self.__inbox=[]


    def addNewArrival(self,senderPhone,arrivalTime,msgTxt):
        msgInfotuple=(senderPhone,arrivalTime,msgTxt)
        singleMsg=[False,msgInfotuple]
        self.__main=self.__inbox.append(singleMsg)
        return self.__main


    someStr=""
    def __str__(self):
        for msg in self.__inbox:
            unread=msg[0]
            msgTuple=msg[1]
            phoneNum=msgTuple[0]
            date=msgTuple[1]
            txt=msgTuple[2]
            return str(unread)+ someStr+" " +str(phoneNum) + someStr+" " + str(txt)+someStr+" "
```

how can change this str code to print appropriately

Comment: What do you mean *"appropriately"*? What does it do now, and what did you expect instead? Note also that `'___init___' != '__init__'`.

Comment: i am expecting  to get similar output to this

Comment: [**Edit the question**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29132195/edit), and answer **both halves** of mine.

Comment: [[False,('111-111-3333',datetime.datetime(2015,1,15,8,15),'bring milk')]

Comment: @JaleneBurta, and what are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you just need to append those strings to a list initialized as `thelist=[]` and then return the `'\n'.join(thelist)`.  But there are several other anomalies in your code.

```
self.__main=self.__inbox.append(singleMsg)
return self.__main
```

This makes no sense.  `append` **always** returns `None`.  Why go to all this bother to save `None` as an attribute of `self` and return it?!

```
someStr=""
def __str__(self):
    for msg in self.__inbox:
        unread=msg[0]
        msgTuple=msg[1]
        phoneNum=msgTuple[0]
        date=msgTuple[1]
        txt=msgTuple[2]
        return str(unread)+ someStr+" " +str(phoneNum) + someStr+" " + str(txt)+someStr+" "
```

Besides the obvious error of `return`ing on the first pass of the loop (so there will never be other passes), this will fail because `someStr` is **not** in scope in the method; you'd need to use `self.someStr` instead, I guess.  (Still looks weird to me but at least it works:-).

So this method must become something like:

```
someStr=""
def __str__(self):
    thelist = []
    someStr = self.someStr
    for msg in self.__inbox:
        unread=msg[0]
        msgTuple=msg[1]
        phoneNum=msgTuple[0]
        date=msgTuple[1]
        txt=msgTuple[2]
        s = str(unread)+ someStr+" " +str(phoneNum) + someStr+" " + str(txt)+someStr+" "
        thelist.append(s)
    return '\n'.join(thelist)
```

Comment: Great, remember to **accept** the answer (click on the checkmark-shaped outline to the left of it).